# Unable to insert data into using Laravel v10 while running an stored procedure with DB facade

Tags: mysql, laravel, stored-procedures

as the title states, I have a controller method that looks something like this

```php
public function store(BuildingRequest $request)
  {
    $building = \DB::select("CALL create_building(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)",
      [
        $request->input('category_id'),
        $request->input('user_id'),
        $request->input('name'),
        $request->input('number'),
        $request->input('street'),
        $request->input('block'),
        $request->input('society'),
        $request->input('rooms'),
        $request->input('yards'),
        $request->input('square_feet'),
        $request->input('total_residents'),
        $request->input('floors'),
        $request->input('units'),
        $request->input('price'),
        $request->input('is_vacant'),
        $request->input('unit_price'),
        $request->input('is_leased'),
        $request->input('is_available_for_rent'),
        $request->input('is_available_for_sale'),
        $request->input('is_under_construction'),
        '\''.implode(',', $request->input('utilities')). '\'',
        $request->input('active')]
    );
    return response()->json([
      'buildings' => $building
    ], 201);
  }
```

---

Using the following logic, I am trying insert the data using the stored procedure name `create_building` but as I run the SP, it breaks and returns me the following error. I am trying to wrap my head around this but I am stuck.

The error looks like the following

```json
{
    "message": "SQLSTATE[01000]: Warning: 1265 Data truncated for column 'utilities' at row 1 (Connection: mysql, SQL: CALL create_building(9880d602-c5aa-44b6-9d70-1cbdb2b931cf,9880a6c7-3197-4c99-87a0-919bbe4a7b44,Paradise Homes,R-160,Street # 2,Block # 3,Kaneez Fatima Society,6,2160.12,240,0,1,1,750000,1,750000,1,0,1,0,'Gas,Electricity,Water,Furnished',1))",
}
```

---

What I have tried is removing the `'\'` from the implode section of the inputs.

My stored procedure looks like this.

```sql
CREATE DEFINER=`sail`@`%` PROCEDURE `create_building`(
    IN category_id CHAR(36)
    ,IN user_id CHAR(36)
    ,IN name VARCHAR(100)
    ,IN number VARCHAR(50)
    ,IN street VARCHAR(100)
    ,IN block VARCHAR(100)
    ,IN society VARCHAR(100)
    ,IN rooms INT
    ,IN yards DECIMAL
    ,IN square_feet DECIMAL
    ,IN total_residents INT
    ,IN floors INT
    ,IN units INT
    ,IN price DECIMAL
    ,IN is_vacant BOOL
    ,IN unit_price DECIMAL
    ,IN is_leased BOOL
    ,IN is_available_for_rent BOOL
    ,IN is_available_for_sale BOOL
    ,IN is_under_construction BOOL
    ,IN utilities VARCHAR(500)
    ,IN active BOOL
)
BEGIN
    SET @id = UUID();
    INSERT INTO buildings 
    (buildings.id, buildings.category_id, buildings.owner_id, buildings.name, buildings.number, buildings.street, buildings.block, buildings.society, buildings.rooms, buildings.yards, buildings.square_feet, buildings.total_residents, buildings.floors, buildings.units, buildings.price, buildings.utilities, buildings.is_vacant, buildings.active, buildings.created_at, buildings.updated_at)
    VALUES
    (@id, category_id, user_id, name, number, street, block, society, rooms, yards, square_feet, total_residents, floors, units, price, utilities, is_vacant, active, NOW(), NOW());
    
    -- Check if building is available for rent
    IF (is_available_for_rent = true) THEN
        SET is_available_for_sale = false;
    END IF;
    
    -- Check if building is available for sale
    IF (is_available_for_sale = true) THEN
        SET is_available_for_rent = false;
    END IF;
    
    -- Check if building is House, Bungalow or Quarter and is avilable for sale or rent
    IF (((is_available_for_rent = true) OR (is_available_for_sale = true)) AND (category_id IN (
    '9880d602-c5aa-44b6-9d70-1cbdb2b931cf', 
    '9880d613-4191-4265-a6b9-60f915b3bcab',
    '9880d64d-d09b-431b-98f0-72e6f4bd63b3') = true)) THEN 
        SET unit_price = price;
    END IF;
    
    -- Check if building is available is unavailable for rent or sale
    IF ((is_available_for_rent = false) AND (is_available_for_sale = false)) THEN
        SET unit_price = 0;
    END IF;
    
    INSERT INTO characteristics 
    (characteristics.id, characteristics.unit_price, characteristics.is_available_for_rent, characteristics.is_available_for_sale, characteristics.is_under_construction, characteristics.building_id)
    VALUES
    (id, unit_price, is_available_for_rent, is_available_for_sale, is_under_construction, @id);
    
    SELECT *
    ,cat.id AS category_id
    ,cat.name AS category_name
    ,cat.created_at AS category_created_at
    ,cat.updated_at AS category_updated_at
    ,chac.unit_price
    ,chac.is_available_for_rent AS characteristic_is_rental
    ,chac.is_available_for_sale AS characteristic_is_salable
    ,chac.is_under_construction AS characteristic_is_under_construction
    FROM buildings bul
    INNER JOIN categories cat ON cat.id = bul.category_id
    INNER JOIN characteristics chac ON bul.id = @id
    WHERE bul.id = @id;
END
```

---

My database schema for both tables look like this.

Table Name: `buildings`:

| id | char(36) |
| --- | --- |
| category_id | char(36) |
| owner_id | char(36) |
| name | varchar(100) |
| number | varchar(50) |
| street | varchar(100) |
| block | varchar(100) |
| society | varchar(255) |
| rooms | int |
| yards | decimal(8,2) |
| square_feet | decimal(8,2) |
| total_residents | int |
| floors | int |
| units | int |
| price | decimal(8,2) |
| is_vacant | tinyint(1) |
| active | tinyint(1) |
| created_at | timestamp |
| updated_at | timestamp |
| deleted_at | timestamp |
| utilities | set('None','Water','Parking','Electricity','Generator','Lift','Gas','Guard','Earthquake Proof','RO PlantFurnished','Fire Safety','Washing Area','Rooftop','Vinyl','Solar','False Ceiling','Commercial','Mosque','Gym','BBQ Area') |

Table Name: `characteristics`

| id | bigint unsigned |
| --- | --- |
| unit_price | decimal(8,2) |
| is_leased | tinyint(1) |
| is_available_for_rent | tinyint(1) |
| is_available_for_sale | tinyint(1) |
| is_under_construction | tinyint(1) |
| building_id | char(36) |

---

Any help will be appreciated, also if you have some changes regarding improving the stored procedure, do lemme know.

For exact information regarding the schema of the buildings and characteristics table, do lemme know, I can attach the migration files for both the table if needed. Any help will be appreciated. I do know the issue is the `utilities` column, but I am not sure what it is.

Comment: Sidenote, tables are a little derpy; you had `| --- | --- |` as the separator, but apparently it needs to be `|---|---|` (no spaces). That being said, I've never used the `set()` column type, but `Furnished` doesn't seem to be a supported value. You have `RO PlantFurnished`, but not `Furnished`, so that value is being truncated (i.e. not included in your update)

Comment: May I ask if this is in production? If it is, nothing can be done, if it is not, why using a Store Procedure? You are "obfuscating" code into a database, instead of letting the PHP code drive the logic, that is not good at all, and you can see that, running a Stored Procedure in Laravel is "ugly", not straightforward like doing `Model::create([...])`. Any insights about that? I would still, move the logic that executes the Store Procedure into a "Domain" class, so you input whataver values you expect to a method of that class and internally run a Store Procedure or whatever you have to

Comment: @matiaslauriti No, not in production, using stored procedure because I wanted to minimize the PHP code, creating and checking if the building was created, then creating new models. So I went with the SP way. This is the only thing that I am using an SP for. Also, I will be moving the logic for creating to the domain class once it's completed. Thanks for your insight :)

Comment: @TimLewis thanks for pointing it out the issue, I missed the comma and hence the issue. Also, thank you for formatting the table, this is the first time I have tried working with tables in markdown 

Comment: @runtimeTerror oh, okay. So, you should not use a SP at all, the issue is maintainability, you are "hiding" code into the database, the database should only be to store data not have logic in there, imaging changing the dtasoirce and now you have incompatibilities, what about updating SPs, what about having more than 1 DB? It is just unmaintainable, believe me, no one is going to like having SPs, so avoid them 100%, you MUST have PHP code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solved.

The issue was that I missed a comma during migration of the `utilities` column

**Now**

```
set('None','Water','Parking','Electricity','Generator','Lift','Gas','Guard','Earthquake Proof','RO Plant','Furnished','Fire Safety','Washing Area','Rooftop','Vinyl','Solar','False Ceiling','Commercial','Mosque','Gym','BBQ Area')
```

**Before**

```
set('None','Water','Parking','Electricity','Generator','Lift','Gas','Guard','Earthquake Proof','RO PlantFurnished','Fire Safety','Washing Area','Rooftop','Vinyl','Solar','False Ceiling','Commercial','Mosque','Gym','BBQ Area')
```